# Как добавить в options набор items

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

Как добавить в options набор items="${moList}". Т.е. не перечислять подобным способом `$("#moId").append( $('<option value="490">КСП</option>'));`  десятки  append

HTML

```
<select id="connectid" name="conectId" onchange="connectIdchange()">
<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
<option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
<option value="10">ЛИНИЯ</option>
            </select>

<select id="moId" name="moId"><option value="0"> </option>
<option value="490">КСП</option>
<option value="510">ККДП</option>
<option value="150">ГБ</option>
<option value="450">ГП</option></select>
```

JSP

```
<form:label path="moId"><spring:message code="label.mo" /></form:label>
<form:select path="moId">
<form:option value="0" label=" " />
<form:options items="${moList}"/>
</form:select>


function connectIdchange(){
        if(user.match(/.*mz.*/) &&( $('#connectid').val() == '10') ) {
        $("#moId").empty();
    
        $("#moId").append( $('<option value="0"> </option>'));
        $("#moId").append( $('<option value="490">КСП</option>'));
        $("#moId").append( $('<option value="510">ККДП</option>'));
        $("#moId").append( $('<option value="150">ГБ</option>'));
        $("#moId").append( $('<option value="450">ГП</option>'));
        }
        else if(user.match(/.*mz.*/) &&( $('#connectid').val() == '1') ) {
            $("#moId").empty();
            $("#moId").append( $('<option value="0"> </option>'));
            $("#moId").append( $('<option items="${moList}"></option>'));
        }
}
```